# Porting Parallel Coordinates code from d3.js v3.5.16 to 4.0

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a working Parallel Coordinates chart visualizing example data with d3.js version 3.5, you can see the code running in [this CodePen here](http://codepen.io/gchriste/pen/xEZjwz).

I would like to rewrite the code to work with the newest version of d3, version 4.0. Would anyone be willing to review my attempt at doing so? I tried to implement the changes from 3.0 to 4.0 that I read about in the [change documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md).

Unfortunately, the data points aren't being drawn correctly, my attempt to port can be seen [here](http://codepen.io/gchriste/pen/rWBemp).

```
// Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) {
  if (d === "name") return false;
  if (d === "Plant" || d === "Chemical" || d === "Pathway" || d === "Gene" || d === "Disease") {
    y[d] = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(data.map(function(p) {
      return p[d];
    })).range([h, 0]);
  } else {
    y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(p) {
        return +p[d];
      }))
      .range([h, 0]);
  }
  return true;
}));

// Add grey background lines for context.
background = svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "background")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", path);

// Add blue foreground lines for focus.
foreground = svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "foreground")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", path);

// Add a group element for each dimension.
var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
  .data(dimensions)
  .enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "dimension")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d) + ")";
  });
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your Pen and change a few simple things. You basically only got your scales wrong - everyone has problems with them. Ordinal scales are now a bit more complex to cover more use cases.

```
// X is a band scale
var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, w]);

// ...

// Your 'category Y' is a point scale
y[d] = d3.scalePoint().domain(data.map(function(p) {
  return p[d];
})).range([h, 0]);
```

I've also changed the orientation of your axes so you can see the labels. But this is just a style issue.

[Forked CodePen](http://codepen.io/b2m9/pen/NbKdEB/)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually working on the same, and I have a working version in v4 of the parallel coordinates chart (brushing and moving the coordinates works too). The javascript code is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451712/appended-text-not-showing-in-d3-v4).