# Appended text not showing in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to "translate" [parallel coordinates example](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281) to the new version of d3 v4. I have a working example with this javascript (which additionally is a good example if anyone is trying to work with the v4 of d3 and has issues with the new functions):

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
    y = {},
    dragging = {};


var line = d3.line(),
    //axis = d3.axisLeft(x),
    background,
    foreground,
    extents;

var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("cars.csv", function(error, cars) {
  // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
    //cars[0] contains the header elements, then for all elements in the header
    //different than "name" it creates and y axis in a dictionary by variable name
  x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
    if(d == "name") {
        return false;
    }
    return y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { 
            return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0]);
  }));

  extents = dimensions.map(function(p) { return [0,0]; });

  // Add grey background lines for context.
  background = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
  foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // Add a group element for each dimension.
  var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(dimensions)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .subject(function(d) { return {x: x(d)}; })
        .on("start", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = x(d);
          background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
        })
        .on("drag", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
          foreground.attr("d", path);
          dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
          x.domain(dimensions);
          g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
        })
        .on("end", function(d) {
          delete dragging[d];
          transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
          transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
          background
              .attr("d", path)
            .transition()
              .delay(500)
              .duration(0)
              .attr("visibility", null);
        }));
  // Add an axis and title.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) {  d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]));})
      //text does not show up because previous line breaks somehow
    .append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9)
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [8,height]]).on("brush start", brushstart).on("brush", brush_parallel_chart));
      })
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);
});

function position(d) {
  var v = dragging[d];
  return v == null ? x(d) : v;
}

function transition(g) {
  return g.transition().duration(500);
}

// Returns the path for a given data point.
function path(d) {
  return line(dimensions.map(function(p) { return [position(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
}

function brushstart() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}


// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush_parallel_chart() {    
    for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){
        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {
            extents[i]=d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);

        }
    }

      foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
            if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
                return true;
            }
          return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
        }) ? null : "none";
      });
}
```

Everything works correctly (brushing on each of the axes, changing the order of the axes...) except that the labels on top of each of the axes are not showing, even though the text tag is appended and the text is written in the tag (can be checked by inspecting the resulting html using the browser). I believe that the code responsible for this is this part, but I am not capable of finding the reason why this happens:

```
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) {  d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]));})
      //text does not show up because previous line breaks somehow
    .append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9)
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Why do the text labels not show?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In D3 **v4** the axis component will explicitly set the fill to `none` on the selection it is called for. From the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/src/axis.js#L110-L114):

```
selection.filter(entering)
    .attr("fill", "none")      // <=== Fill set to none by D3
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("text-anchor", orient === right ? "start" : orient === left ? "end" : "middle");
```

This will create the following code:

[image]

in contrast to the code generated by v3:

[image]

The `<text>` elements will inherit these properties, because they are children of these groups, whereby hiding the texts.

To show the labels you need to explicitly style them, which can be done

1. Via CSS:

   ```
   .axis text {
     fill:black;   /* <== Set the fill */
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
     cursor: move;
   }
   ```

   Working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Meev2Af2Ncdqysm85po?p=preview).
2. By setting the `fill` attribute on the `<text>` element itself:

   ```
   .append("text")
     .attr("fill", "black")          // <=== Set the fill
   //  .style("fill", "black")       // Will also work when using .style()
     .style("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("y", -9) 
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
   ```

   Working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RkWBgQ6oi584H3212WrM?p=preview).

Comment: These are not really working demos. I know this was not a question but the brushes are not working in the example posted. They don't reset filtering when brush is removed.

Comment: @konrad The demos are just replicas of OP's code with one line added to solve the problem the question was all about. I don't claim them to be error-free or fully-functional.

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to point that out in case others noticed as well. Care to comment on how to possibly address that issue as well?