# Multiple brushes on an axis in parallel coordinate in d3 V4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a parallel coordinate in d3 V4 (with a lot of pain)which has both numerical and ordinal axis, with basic features like axis dragging, brushing, brush snapping.
Here is the working sample 
http://plnkr.co/edit/dCNuBsaDNBwr7CrAJUBe?p=preview

I am looking to have multiple brushes in an axis, (for example I want to brush 0.2 to 0.5 and 0.7 to 0.9 of column1 in my example at the same time). So basically based on multiple brush areas the corresponding lines should be highlighted. 
Please suggest some way to do this.
Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
   stroke-opacity: .4;  
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-opacity: .7;
}

.brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .3;
  stroke: #fff;

  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  cursor: move;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>


var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scalePoint().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
    y = {},
    dragging = {};


var line = d3.line(),
    //axis = d3.axisLeft(x),
    background,
    foreground,
    extents;


 var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "parcoords")
    .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
    .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

var svg = container.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var quant_p = function(v){return (parseFloat(v) == v) || (v == "")};     

d3.json("convertcsv.json", function(error, cars) {

    dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]);

    x.domain(dimensions);

    dimensions.forEach(function(d) {
    var vals = cars.map(function(p) {return p[d];});
    if (vals.every(quant_p)){ 
     y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { 
            return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0])

        console.log(y[d]);
      }
    else{
     vals.sort();           
      y[d] = d3.scalePoint()
              .domain(vals.filter(function(v, i) {return vals.indexOf(v) == i;}))
              .range([height, 0],1);
       }

  })


 extents = dimensions.map(function(p) { return [0,0]; });


  // Add grey background lines for context.
  background = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
  foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);



  // Add a group element for each dimension.

  var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(dimensions)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .subject(function(d) { return {x: x(d)}; })
        .on("start", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = x(d);
          background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
        })
        .on("drag", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
          foreground.attr("d", path);
          dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
          x.domain(dimensions);
          g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
        })
        .on("end", function(d) {
          delete dragging[d];
          transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
          transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
          background
              .attr("d", path)
            .transition()
              .delay(500)
              .duration(0)
              .attr("visibility", null);
        }));


  // Add an axis and title.
   var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension");
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) {  d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]));})
      //text does not show up because previous line breaks somehow
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9) 
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        if(y[d].name == 'r'){
         // console.log(this);

        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [8,height]]).on("brush start", brushstart).on("brush", go_brush).on("brush", brush_parallel_chart).on("end", brush_end));
        }


      else if(y[d].name == 'n')
             d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [15,height]]).on("brush start", brushstart).on("brush", go_brush).on("brush", brush_parallel).on("end", brush_end_ordinal)); 


      })
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);  
});  // closing

function position(d) {
  var v = dragging[d];
  return v == null ? x(d) : v;
}

function transition(g) {
  return g.transition().duration(500);
}

// Returns the path for a given data point.
function path(d) {
  return line(dimensions.map(function(p) { return [position(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
}

function go_brush() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}


invertExtent = function(y) {
  return domain.filter(function(d, i) { return y === range[i]; });
};


function brushstart(selectionName) {
  foreground.style("display", "none")

  //console.log(selectionName);

  var dimensionsIndex = dimensions.indexOf(selectionName);

  //console.log(dimensionsIndex);

  extents[dimensionsIndex] = [0, 0];

  foreground.style("display", function(d) {
    return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
        if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
            return true;
        }
      return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
    }) ? null : "none";
  });
}



// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush_parallel_chart() { 

   for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){


        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {
         //if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;

            extents[i]=d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);

    }

}

     foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
            if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
                return true;
            }
          return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
        }) ? null : "none";
      }); 
}    


function brush_end(){



  if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return; // Only transition after input.
  if (!d3.event.selection) return; // Ignore empty selections.


for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){

    if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {

  extents[i]=d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);

   extents[i][0] = Math.round( extents[i][0] * 10 ) / 10;
   extents[i][1] = Math.round( extents[i][1] * 10 ) / 10;



    d3.select(this).transition().call(d3.event.target.move, extents[i].map(y[dimensions[i]]));

     }

  }

}

//   brush for ordinal cases
function brush_parallel() {


for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){

        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {


       var  yScale = y[dimensions[i]];
       var selected =  yScale.domain().filter(function(d){
            // var s = d3.event.target.extent();
          var s = d3.event.selection;

      return (s[0] <= yScale(d)) && (yScale(d) <= s[1])

      });


var temp = selected.sort();
extents[i] = [temp[temp.length-1], temp[0]];


   }

}

foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
            if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
                return true;
            }
          //var p_new = (y[p].ticks)?d[p]:y[p](d[p]); 
          //return extents[i][1] <= p_new && p_new <= extents[i][0];
        return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
        }) ? null : "none";
      });     
}




function brush_end_ordinal(){

  console.log("hhhhh");


  if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return; // Only transition after input.

  if (!d3.event.selection) return; // Ignore empty selections.

  for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){

        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {


       var  yScale = y[dimensions[i]];
       var selected =  yScale.domain().filter(function(d){
      // var s = d3.event.target.extent();
      var s = d3.event.selection;

      return (s[0] <= yScale(d)) && (yScale(d) <= s[1])

      });

  var temp = selected.sort();
  extents[i] = [temp[temp.length-1], temp[0]];

if(selected.length >1)
d3.select(this).transition().call(d3.event.target.move, extents[i].map(y[dimensions[i]]));


     }  
 } 



}

</script>
```

Comment: I've used [this](http://bl.ocks.org/ludwigschubert/0236fa8594c4b02711b2606a8f95f605) approach a couple of times. It'd be great if you could try using it and get back if you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems a basic method of multiple brushing. The problem I am facing is that when I select a brushed region and click and start brushing on other points in the same axis,the earlier brushed region is gone. I can store the initial brush extent in some global array, but is there a way to preserve the initial brushed part. Any code sample with multiple brush in parallel coordinate will be really helpful .Thanks again and Sorry for my English.

Comment: Yeah I'll get you a working example (for 1 dimension) soon. And you're absolutely fine with your English. No sweat!

Comment: Hey thanks alot, Meanwhile I ll try implementing it and also look for other resources. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, I got one similar link http://bl.ocks.org/bollwyvl/8463137 , but it implements d3.svg.multibrush() in V3. I am having trouble finding similar function in V4 . Please suggest . Thanks

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't get back to you (was/am too busy with work). I'll get it done by tomorrow for sure. In that similar example, [this](https://github.com/humanitiesplusdesign/d3.svg.multibrush) is the library used which was written just for v3 - thanks for that. I'll try using that (with v4 changes) or else the standard approach (mentioned earlier) and get that done.

Comment: Hey thanks, dont say sorry. its totally cool :) I understand.. its just I happened to go through that example so wanted to update..Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, I found multi brush in V4 in this https://github.com/BigFatDog/parcoords-es/tree/master/src , it looks the same library as you said but in V4 , but there are no examples how to import and use that.

Comment: Sorry, if I am being unpatient , just sharing whatever update I am getting. :)

Comment: Hey I just wrote the library for v4 and tested it with your code and guess what it works. Just need to fix the ordinal axis brushing and I'll post the plunkr. Alright?

Comment: Really .. super awesome ..!! Pls plss post it on plunkr . Meanwhile I will also see the case for ordinal brushing and try to fix that. But seriously big heartly thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of multi brush in d3 V4 is there in https://github.com/BigFatDog/parcoords-es

But I guess demo examples are not there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Plunkr using multiple brushes in d3 v4 and of course working on your parallel chart:

[Code Plunkr for multi brush](http://plnkr.co/edit/8BiT50TiKd1JeIzVuiTa?p=preview)

https://github.com/shashank2104/d3.svg.multibrush (I'll suggest the v4 patch to the guy who has written the v3 version once it's completely done)

There's one thing that's bothering me which is the brush clicking, **as of now, the brushing works with CLICK to start, MOUSEMOVE and CLICK to end**. Just play around with the brushing and you'll notice the difference.

The new brushing function is the default one (as follows);

```
// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush() {
  var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) { return !y[p].brush.empty(); }),
  extents = actives.map(function(p) { return y[p].brush.extent(); });
  foreground.style("display", function(d) {
  return actives.every(function(p, i) {
        return extents[i].some(function(e){
            return e[0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= e[1];
        });
  }) ? null : "none";
 });
}
```

I'll be working on it and hopefully it'll be ready by morning.

Until then, ordinal axis shouldn't be a problem to fix.

I'll keep you posted and edit the same post. (It'd be nice if you could not accept the answer as the right one until it's completely fixed. It'll be on my plate to fix)

Let me know if you come across any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Shashank thanks a lot for the working example, Its like first working example of multi brush in V4. I observed  the points you mentioned about brushing.Its a bit different from the traditional brushing method. But the multi brush library from V3 has the conventional brushing way , right.

I have placed the code for ordinal brushing also in your (default) brush function.

```
function brush() {
  var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) { return !y[p].brush.empty(); }),
      extents = actives.map(function(p) { return y[p].brush.extent(); });

  foreground.style("display", function(d) {
    return actives.every(function(p, i) {
      var p_new = (y[p].ticks)?d[p]:y[p](d[p]);
            return extents[i].some(function(e){
                //return e[0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= e[1];
        return e[0] <= p_new && p_new <= e[1];
            });
    }) ? null : "none";
  });
}
```

In my plunkr example, I have used d3.brushY() functions which are in V4 and thats why I have to implement invert functions (for numerical axis , referred  from [Appended text not showing in d3 v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451712/appended-text-not-showing-in-d3-v4/41452514)) and refeered http://bl.ocks.org/chrisbrich/4173587 for ordinal axis. With these combinations I was able to do brush snapping also.

Also Is there a way that I can do brush snapping also (both numerical and ordinal axis) with your multi brush plunkr example.

I know I am asking more, but basically two points:
1) Is there a way to do multi brushing like that in V3, like as click- drag - leave !
2) Brush snapping (numerical and ordinal) in your multi brush example ?

Thanks again for all your effort and time , means a lot. I am making points so that once you suggest V4 patch, its ll be like fully good.:)

Comment: Hey, I think I may have to write it again with a lot of changes which might take some time as it needs to expose v4 brush selection methods (which it doesn't as of now as it wasn't available in v3). Snapping can be done on this code as well but I think if you're patient enough, we can put together a v4 version with a working example. What do you think?

Comment: Sure sure , although I am sort of new to d3 , I understand that this is quite complicated. Specially I stuggled a lot with brush selection. So take your time. I will update here if I happen to progress anywhere. And really thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure. I've wanted to write a multi brush library anyway as I've used it a couple of times (never used it for a parallel chart though). I'll do that for v4 and post this one as a working example.

Comment: hey that would be great. As I am quite new to d3, I dont know how much help I can offer you in writing this library. But I will try my best. It would be great to have multi brush lib in V4 and with parallel coordinate :)

Comment: Thanks Nicole. I'll keep you posted. :)

Comment: hey hope you are doing well. I tried a bit with multi brush in V4, a few days back but not much success. So I didnt update u. :(

Comment: I'm hopeful of getting it done by this weekend. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: hey , shasank .. that would be really great. take your time. All the best. thanks :)

Comment: Hello, I was wondering  that is there a way where we can click the axis labels ( like in my original plunkr example, Can we make that 'value_2' and 'value_3' labels of axis titled column_4 clickable  !! ) With that , we can store the clicked values of corresponding axises in global arrays and then simply draw the path.. So basically I mean, instead of brushing multi ple parts of an axis , we click and drw the path. THis will work only in case of ordinal axis bcoz all the lines will be passing through particular labels only.

Comment: Yes, that is possible and yes, you're absolutely right about the catch (only ordinal axes). If you wanna try doing that, give it a try and create a new question if you face any issues doing that. It should be fairly simple though. Do tag me within the new question (if you create one).

Comment: Yea ofcourse , I am going to tag you. Could you please help me in making those labels clickable . For instance, if I click on "value_2" so simply value_2 output in my console. Then I think I would be able to frame it atleast for ordinal axis. After that if I face some issues, I will post and tag you.

Comment: Ideally, you're supposed to create a new question for that as well but anyway, here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9bM74F2nrRREmxn1xSNi?p=preview). Check the console. And I think we're discussing here a lot which is definitely not the right approach. Maybe we can email (as you're not yet available on SO chat).

Comment: hey, sorry I didnt notice that, it seem part of same question. thanks again for that. Next time I will post a new question regarding the new approach and comment here for the old approach. Will that be ok ? Here is my gmail- nicolenotkidman01 . Thanks for the guidance, you are great in d3. I will wait for your multi brush feature in d3 V4 and tag you in other questions.